# Python - lambda function works by itself, but in a for loop - it doesn't

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Very weird case. I created some lists of ID numbers from DF columns which I want to lookup in another DF (final_df) and set a 'YES'/'NO' value in a correspondent column if they are found. It works perfectly when I run a lambda function by itself, but I tried to for loop it - and it doesn't.

```
df1['id_column'] = ['ABCDEF', 'BDCJG', 'HJAYR']
df2['id_column'] = ['NBJOAN', 'NAJOJ', 'NAIRG']

# The real version has duplicates so I convert it to sets here
df1_id_list = set(df1['id_column']
df2_id_list = set(df2['id_column']
```

This works just fine:

```
final_df['df1'] = final_df['id_column'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if x in df1_id_list else 'NO')
```

But THIS brings KeyError 'df1_id_list':

```
df_list = ['df1', 'df2']

for df in df_list:
   final_df[df] = final_df['id_column'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if x in vars()[df + '_id_list'] else 'NO')
```

I don't want to lose scalability, so why on Earth does the second one not work?

Comment: `df1` is not the same as `'df1'`.

Comment: Are you getting a `KeyError`?

Comment: @FredLarson corrected it, thanks

Comment: No, it goes beyond just a typo. You can't concatenate two strings and use the result as an identifier. `'df1_id_list'` is not the same as `df1_id_list`.

Comment: @FredLarson which is why I put vars()['df1_id_list'] which should 'convert' the string into a corresponding variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) wasn't working it's because  `vars()` without any argument acts like `locals()` and since a dictionary comprehension has its own scope it has no variable named a `df1_id_list` or `df2_id_list`. You can use `eval()` (Edited based on corrected question):

```
df_list = ['df1', 'df2']
for df in df_list:
   final_df[df] = final_df['id_column'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if x in eval(df + '_id_list') else 'NO')
```

You can try also with `globals()`, which returns a dictionary with all the defined variables:

```
df_list = ['df1', 'df2']
for df in df_list:
       final_df[df] = final_df['id_column'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if x in globals()[df + '_id_list'] else 'NO')
```

Comment: That was my spelling mistake, I corrected it. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, no problem. And, did you test it with `globals()[df + '_id_list']` or  `eval(df + '_id_list')`?. I tested it with eval and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to print your internal variable name to the dataframe and not just use an index like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
df1['id_column'] = ['ABCDEF', 'BDCJG', 'HJAYR']
df2['id_column'] = ['NBJOAN', 'NAJOJ', 'NAIRG']
final_df['id_column'] = ['ABCDEF', 'NAJOJ', 'ZZZZZ']

df1_id_list = set(df1['id_column'])
df2_id_list = set(df2['id_column'])

df_list = [df1, df2]
index = 1
for df in df_list:
    final_df[f'df_{index}'] = final_df['id_column'].apply(lambda x: 'YES' if x in set(df['id_column']) else 'NO')
    index += 1
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
id_column df_1 df_2
0    ABCDEF  YES   NO
1     NAJOJ   NO  YES
2     ZZZZZ   NO   NO
```